# How to pass variable value in Swift to HTML?

Tags: ios, swift

I have HTML page, and Swift project, I want to pass variable value to html

like
in abc.swift

var name = "someName"

index.html

**want to show someName** in p tag

if any one has objective-C code it will also helpful for me

Comment: call the url passing the variable name, example: yourURL?name=someName (your variable name). You can read more about here: http://html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

Comment: Thanks for answer..can you give any example in swift? or can you describe how to show this value in HTML

Answer (score 6):

In swift4:

WebView is deprecated. You'll have to use WKWebView instead to display your content. You also need to implement WKNavigationDelegate.

Create a reference/outlet for your webView in your vc. In your viewDidLoad, make your vc a delegate of WKNavigationDelegate protocol:

```
var wkwebView: WKWebView 
wkwebView.navigationDelegate = self //in viewDidLoad
```

Assuming your html file is in your project. Load your html into your wkWebView:

```
do{
    guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourFile", ofType: "html") else { return }
    let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: .utf8)
    let baseUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    wkwebView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: baseUrl)
} catch {
    print("HTML File error")
}
```

implement WKNavigationDelegate method and call your js function passing the value you want your js to process:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
   wkwebView.evaluateJavaScript("populate(\"hello world\")", completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Now in your html body, you should have a function that will receive the parameter to process.

```
...
<p id="test"></p>
<script>
    function populate(param) {
        var myelement = document.getElementById("test");
        myelement.innerHTML= param;
    }
</script>
...
```

Your passed value should now display in your wkWebView. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 4):

If your HTML file loaded in UIWebView, you can do that using JS and [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) method of webView. this method allows communication between HTML and the native code via JS, below an example

```
let param = "MyParam"
webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("myJSFunction('\(param)')")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not find "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" in swift

Comment: that is because it must be on a UIWebView instance.